# Magento 1.5.1 - USPS Shipping Method error

Tags: zend-framework, magento, magento-1.5

Using USPS shipping method returns and error message on the front end of:

> This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.

The debug log shows the following:

```
2011-11-03T20:50:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RateV3Request USERID="999PIIAN9999"><Package ID="0"><Service>ALL</Service><ZipOrigination>92264</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>20500</ZipDestination><Pounds>1</Pounds><Ounces>8</Ounces><Container>FLAT RATE BOX</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Machinable>true</Machinable></Package></RateV3Request>

[result] => Array
    (
        [error] => Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted
        [code] => 0
    )

[__pid] => 23858
)
```

Has anyone a solution? Or any ideas on the cause.

Magneto version 1.5.1.0

Thanks.

James